# Javascript Google Maps API draggable marker click through

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is it normal behaviour that when I create a non-draggable marker and click, events work as they should.

But when I set `draggable: true`, draggable works good. But when clicking the marker it also clicks through it and sets another maker under it.

Is there something I am missing?

Update:

```
// marker clicks
function makeDescriptionShower(map, marker, uuid) {
return function() {
    console.log("event makeDesccriptionShower");
    marker.info.open(map, marker);
    //ED
    resetForm();
    editPOI(uuid, marker);
    ....
    }
}

.....

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', makeDescriptionShower(map, marker, uuid));


//map clicks
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    console.log("map event");
    cleanArrays();
    updatingFlag(false);
    resetForm();
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = e.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = e.latLng.lng();
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
});
```

Comment: I expect this is normal behaviour since by the sounds of it your map is also listening for click events.  Provide some of your code demonstrating how your attaching to these events so we may better understand.

Comment: Yes I also have map click listener

Comment: @loanburger because I saw somewhere Google examples where marker have also listeners but marker is not click trough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I continue someone else project.
There was error inside `makeDescriptionShower` with other function that made this click trough marker behaviour. I fixed everything by putting crashing code line inside `window.onload=function(){`.