# Google Maps Javascript API draggable markers don't trigger neither "click" nor "gmp-click" event on touch devices

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile, touch, touch-event

As I have written in the title, I am dealing with Google Maps Javascript API.
In particular I am using the last released Advanced Markers for their customization capabilities.

These elements can be set to be draggable (by declaring the appropriate property in their option literal object) and support both the "click" and the "gmp-click" event, as stated in the official documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers?hl=en).
Now, I am experiencing this issue when I try to use my map on a touch enabled device: if a marker is set to be draggable, either the "click" or the "gmp-click" events aren't triggered (or seem to be not triggered)

I have seen there is already another similar question to my one, i.e. this one

[Javascript Google Maps API draggable marker click through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41707228/javascript-google-maps-api-draggable-marker-click-through)

anyway, instead having the click event that "pass through" the marker, my draggable markers seem not triggering any event at all. As a matter of fact I attached a click event to the markers that opens an Infowindow and pan the map to the marer position. I also attached a click event to the map as well, that alerts the latitude and longitude of the clicked position. When I click both on the map and a "fixed" marker I get the correct behaviour, but when I click on a draggable marker, nothing happens (so the click event is not passed to the map).

Here are some code snippet of what I did:

> <div id="map">

> <script>
>
> ```
>     const { Map, InfoWindow } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
>     const {AdvancedMarkerElement} = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
>
>     let map = new Map(document.getElementById("map");
>
>     map.addListener("click", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
>         alert(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toJSON());
>     });
>
>     const markerPositions = [
>        {
>             position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91721, 151.2263),
>             draggable: false,
>        },
>        {
>             position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91539, 151.2282),
>             draggable: true,
>     }];
>       
>     let markers = [];
>
>     for (let i = 0; i < markerPositions.length; i++) {
>         const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
>                             map: map,
>                             position: markerPositions[i].position
>                             gmpDraggable: markerPositions[i].draggable ? true : false;
>         });
>          
>           
>         marker.addEventListener("gmp-click", () => {
>               
>             const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
>                                    content: "This marker has been clicked",
>             });
>             infowindow.open({
>                 anchor: marker,
>                 map: map,      
>             });
>             map.panTo(marker.position);
>               
>         });
>         markers.push(marker);
>
>     }
> ```
>
> </script>

Here, the first marker works fine both on desktop and mobile (touch enabled) devices, while the second one (the draggable marker) can't trigger any event and action.

So, does anyone have any idea on how to make the draggable marker able to trigger click event on touch enabled devices? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue seems to be related to a common problem where draggable markers on touch-enabled devices sometimes do not trigger click events. This is because the device registers the touch as a potential drag start, thus consuming the touch and not allowing it to be recognised as a click.

A workaround for this issue is to detect a drag end and then only open the InfoWindow or perform an action if the marker has not been dragged. This involves keeping track of the marker's position at the start of the drag and then comparing it to the position at the end of the drag. If they're the same, then it's treated as a click event.

Let's implement this solution:

1. You'll need to add `dragstart` and `dragend` event listeners to your draggable markers.
2. On `dragstart`, save the marker's position.
3. On `dragend`, compare the marker's current position with the saved position. If they're the same, treat it as a click.

Here's how you can modify your code to implement this:

```js
// ... rest of your code ...

for (let i = 0; i < markerPositions.length; i++) {
    const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
        map: map,
        position: markerPositions[i].position,
        gmpDraggable: markerPositions[i].draggable ? true : false,
    });
    
    let startPos = null;

    marker.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
        startPos = marker.position.toJSON();
    });

    marker.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
        const endPos = marker.position.toJSON();

        // Check if the marker has been dragged
        if (startPos.lat === endPos.lat && startPos.lng === endPos.lng) {
            // Handle this as a click event
            openInfoWindow(marker);
        }
    });

    marker.addEventListener("gmp-click", () => {
        openInfoWindow(marker);
    });

    markers.push(marker);
}

function openInfoWindow(marker) {
    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "This marker has been clicked",
    });

    infowindow.open({
        anchor: marker,
        map: map,      
    });

    map.panTo(marker.position);
}
```

The function `openInfoWindow` will open an InfoWindow and pan the map to the marker's position. It is triggered when the marker is clicked or, for draggable markers on touch devices, when a drag ends but the marker's position hasn't changed.

This solution should provide a consistent experience across devices and allow for the expected behaviour when interacting with draggable markers on touch-enabled devices.

Comment: Thanks @Shila Mosammami ! That is a nice trick, anyway in order to get the infowindow to be triggered you need at least to slightly drag the marker. When you actually just tap on it, without moving it, it seems that the dragstart and dragend events aren't fired...so what you suggest is nice because sometimes, on a mobile device, if you want just tap it is likely that you start a slight drag event. But when you can just tap, the trick doesn't work (I am trying it on Chrome for Android)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have found a possible solution.

After reading this

[Google Maps AdvancedMarker hover listener function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76860379/google-maps-advancedmarker-hover-listener-function-not-working)

I have added an event listener to the content of the marker when the device is "touch-enabled". Furthermore (read my comment in the above post), I check if the marker is draggable or not (it seems that the "trick" to attach the event listener to the marker content works just if the marker is set to be draggable).
In particular I have attached a "touchstart" event to the draggable markers when the device is touch-enabled.
This seems working pretty well on my phone.

Here is how I edited my code:

> ```
> function isTouchDevice() {
>     return (('ontouchstart' in window) ||
>             (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) ||
>             (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
> }
> const { Map, InfoWindow } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
> const {AdvancedMarkerElement} = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
>
> let map = new Map(document.getElementById("map");
>
> map.addListener("click", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
>     alert(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toJSON());
> });
>
> const markerPositions = [
>    {
>         position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91721, 151.2263),
>         draggable: false,
>    },
>    {
>         position: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.91539, 151.2282),
>         draggable: true,
> }];
>   
> let markers = [];
>
> for (let i = 0; i < markerPositions.length; i++) {
>     const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
>                         map: map,
>                         position: markerPositions[i].position
>                         gmpDraggable: markerPositions[i].draggable ? true : false;
>     });
>      
>     if (!isTouchDevice) {  
>         marker.addEventListener("gmp-click", () => {
>           
>             const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
>                                    content: "This marker has been clicked",
>             });
>             infowindow.open({
>                 anchor: marker,
>                 map: map,      
>             });
>             map.panTo(marker.position);
>           
>         });
>     }
>     else {
>         if (!marker.gmpDraggable) {
>             marker.addEventListener("gmp-click", () => {
>           
>                 const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
>                                    content: "This marker has been clicked",
>                 });
>                 infowindow.open({
>                     anchor: marker,
>                     map: map,      
>                 });
>                 map.panTo(marker.position);
>           
>             });
>         }
>         else {
>             marker.content.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
>           
>                 const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
>                                    content: "This marker has been clicked",
>                 });
>                 infowindow.open({
>                     anchor: marker,
>                     map: map,      
>                 });
>                 map.panTo(marker.position);
>         }
>     }
>     markers.push(marker);
>
> }
> ```