# gmp-advanced-marker neither draggable nor clickable

Tags: google-maps, web-component, google-web-component

working with the google maps web component.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/web-components/overview

I have this code

```js
        <div class="map-container">
            <gmp-map
                center="39.46598273118431,-0.3835740844457525"
                zoom="12"
                map-id="DEMO_MAP_ID"
            >
                <gmp-advanced-marker
                    position="39.46598273118431,-0.3835740844457525"
                    title="Resto"
                    gmpDraggable="true"
                ></gmp-advanced-marker>
            </gmp-map>
        </div>

        <script>
            const m = document.querySelector("gmp-advanced-marker");
            m.addEventListener("gmp-click", (evt) => {
                console.log(evt);
            });
        </script>
```

the marker is rendered correctly, but it is not draggable, and nor does the `gmp-click` event fire when I click the marker.

Any ideas what I've got wrong

Update: not clickable explained by [Google Maps Javascript API draggable markers don't trigger neither "click" nor "gmp-click" event on touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77044160/google-maps-javascript-api-draggable-markers-dont-trigger-neither-click-nor?rq=2) Still can't get draggable though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, there's nothing particularly *wrong* about your code.

Still, I'd make sure to run the scripts only after the map has been properly loaded (e.g. via the [inline script `callback`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Loading_the_Maps_API)):

```html
<script async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap&libraries=maps,marker&v=beta">
</script>
```

Also, since you're using `addEventListener("gmp-click", ...)`, make sure you're on the [`beta` channel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers#AdvancedMarkerElement.addEventListener).

Putting it together, your click events should now work:

```js
function initMap() {
  const m = document.querySelector("gmp-advanced-marker");
  
  // the `beta` APIs are now loaded -> gmp-clicks can now be registered
  m.addEventListener("gmp-click", (evt) => {
    console.log('addEventListener gmp-click event', evt);
  });
}
```

Finally, I couldn't determine why the marker isn't draggable by inline-setting `gmpDraggable="true"`. Likely a `beta` bug? Nonetheless, you can manually set this properly on the web component and this seems to work fine:

```js
function initMap() {
  const m = document.querySelector("gmp-advanced-marker");
  
  // note that `m.setOptions({ draggable: true})` won't work here...
  m.gmpDraggable = true;

  // returns void
  m.addListener("dragend", (evt) => {
    console.log('dragend evt', evt);
  });
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle repro](https://jsfiddle.net/vqart4y5/4/).

Comment: This definitely helps